# How to get body message from every failed sampler in JMeter thread group

Tags: jmeter

I am new to jMeter so hope you can help me out.

I have a thread group with several HTTP request samplers. I am sending an email every time any sampler fails. The thing is I would like to collect the names + response bodies of the several failed samplers to send in the email.

Can anybody please give an example of how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be using [Simple Data Writer listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) configured to save only failed requests, there you can choose whatever metrics you need to store:

[image]

---

Another option is using [JSR223 test elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) to extract the "interesting" fields from the failed requests:

[image]

in the above example the sampler gets the label and the body from the previous result and stores them into `${requestName}` and `${responseData}` JMeter Variables which you can use wherever you want. More information on these `prev`, `vars` and other JMeter API shorthands: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)